# 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView'.'

Tags: c#

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView'.

Which is pointing at the line

```
foreach(GridView dr in GridView1.Rows)
```

I want to delete multiple rows in the table. When  I select 2 rows and click the delete button this error pop up. I tried a lot to solve. But I didn't get.

Here is the aspx.cs

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlInputCheckBox chk;
    foreach (GridView dr in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        chk = (HtmlInputCheckBox)dr.FindControl("ch");
        if (chk.Checked)
        {
            db.exenonquery("delete from tbl_employee where Employee_Id='" + chk.Value + "'");
        }
    }
    db.fillgrid("Select * from tbl_employee", GridView1);
}
```

Here is the common class cs

```
public void fillgrid(string sql,GridView dv)
{
    dv.DataSource = exedataset(sql);
    dv.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: The is totally clear you are trying to iterate through your rows as if each was a GridView try `foreach (var dr in GridView1.Rows)`.

Comment: Also parameterize your query, value concatenation like you use is unsafe, prone to errors, and hurts performance. Otherwise, this question has nothing to do with sql, sql server, asp.net or ado.net

Answer (score 0):

Your using type GridView - that is the "whole" gridview type.

Your for each should be on a GridView "row"

eg:

```
        foreach (GridViewRow dr in GridView1.Rows)
```